# incompatible gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm seeing an error message in the build.gradle file for an android library in my app. The dependencies block is shown below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7@aar'
}
```

The message I'm seeing is:

```
all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification
```

Apparently, both version 27.0.2 and 21.0.3

```
Found versions 27.0.2, 21.0.3. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 less... (⌘F1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overwrite old LIB

```
 dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
            compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
            compile 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7@aar'
            //overwrite old LIB
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'  

        }
```

Comment: i saw, it worked but so isn't allowing me to accept the answer yet, i have to wait two minutes